# How to trigger two button by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

here is my html code

```
<ul id="btn-list">
    <li><span><button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Btn1</button></span></li>
    <li><span><button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Btn2</button></span></li>
    <li><span><button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Btn3</button></span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to trigger `click` event of `btn1` and `btn2`, but I don't have any idea how to write the specific button selector where no name and id attribute not assigned to the respective buttons

```
$("#btn-list ???").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector

> Select all elements at an index less than `index` within the matched set.

```
$('#btn-list button:lt(2)').trigger('click');
```

OR, You can use [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('#btn-list').find('button:eq(0), button:eq(1)').trigger('click');
```

Comment: if i want to trigger first button then?

Comment: @AshisBiswas, You can also use `$('#btn-list button:first').trigger('click');` or `$('#btn-list button:eq(0)').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 1):

You can see working solution below

When you run below snippen Click on Button1 to trigger one button click on Click on Button 2 for Both Button Clicks

```js
$("button:first").click(function () {
    update($("span:first"));
});
$("button:last").click(function () {
    $("button:first").trigger('click');
    update($("span:last"));
});

function update(j) {
    var n = parseInt(j.text(), 10);
    j.text(n + 1);
}
```

```css
button { margin:10px; }
div { color:blue; font-weight:bold; }
span { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button #1</button>
<button>Button #2</button>

<div><span>0</span> button #1 clicks.</div>
<div><span>0</span> button #2 clicks.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="btn-list">
<li><span><button class="btn  btn-warning btn-lg">Btn1</button></span></li>
<li><span><button class="btn  btn-warning btn-lg">Btn2</button></span></li>
<li><span><button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Btn3</button></span></li>
```

```
$('#btn-list').slice(1,3).on('click','button', function (evt) {
 //-- do stuff
});
```

Comment: I cant assign any extra name or id attribute.